# How to validate the message that is receive in socket in C#

Tags: c#, validation, sockets

First 4 characters represent the length of message.
I want to validate by getting first 4 bit of the  received message to find its length and verify whether it matches with the first 4 bit.
For example
First four bit give me 45 and message length is 49 then this is true  (45 body + first 4 bit length)
else first four bit give 45 but message length 35 . drop this message. This where the problem is.

Class:

```
internal static void BeginReceive(this Client client)
    {   


        client.outBuffer.Clear();
        client.KindOfMessage = KindMessage.Unknown;
        client.MessageLength = int.MaxValue;

        using (client.mreBeginReceive = new ManualResetEvent(false))
        {
            try
            {
                while (!client.closed)
                {
                    client.mreBeginReceive.Reset();
                    client.socket.BeginReceive(client.socketBuffer, 0, Const.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, EndReceive, client);
                    client.mreInit.SetIfNotNull();
                    client.mreBeginReceive.WaitOne();
                    client.mreIsConnected.WaitOne();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                client.HandleError(e);
            }
        }
    }
   private static void EndReceive(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var client = (Client)result.AsyncState;

        if (client.closed)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            var receive = client.socket.EndReceive(result);

            if (receive == 0)
            {
                client.Disconnect();
                return;
            }

            client.ProcessNewData(receive);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            client.HandleError(e);
        }

        client.mreBeginReceive.SetIfNotNull();
    }

    internal static void ProcessNewData(this Client client, int receive)
    {

        lock (client.outBuffer)
        {
            client.outBuffer.AddRange(client.socketBuffer.Take(receive)); 


            do
            {
                client.EnvelopeRead();

                if (client.outBuffer.Count >= client.MessageLength)
                {
                    var msg = client.outBuffer.GetRange(0, client.MessageLength).ToArray();
                    client.outBuffer.RemoveRange(0, client.MessageLength);

                    client.RaiseMessageReceived(msg, client.KindOfMessage);

                    client.KindOfMessage = KindMessage.Unknown;
                    client.MessageLength = client.outBuffer.Count >= Const.TotalSizeOfEnvelope ? 0 : int.MaxValue;
                }

            } while (client.outBuffer.Count >= client.MessageLength);
        }
    }
```

**and process data as following**

```
internal static void ProcessNewData(this Client client, int receive)
{
lock (client.outBuffer)
{
    client.outBuffer.AddRange(client.socketBuffer.Take(receive)); 
    do
    {
        client.EnvelopeRead();

        if (client.outBuffer.Count >= client.MessageLength)
        {
            var msg = client.outBuffer.GetRange(0,  client.MessageLength).ToArray();
            client.outBuffer.RemoveRange(0, client.MessageLength);

            client.RaiseMessageReceived(msg, client.KindOfMessage);

            client.KindOfMessage = KindMessage.Unknown;
            client.MessageLength = client.outBuffer.Count >= Const.TotalSizeOfEnvelope ? 0 : int.MaxValue;
        }

    } while (client.outBuffer.Count >= client.MessageLength);
}
```

**i change it as **

```
internal static void ProcessNewData(this Client client, int receive)
{
    lock (client.outBuffer)
    {
        client.outBuffer.AddRange(client.socketBuffer.Take(receive)); 
        List<Byte> a = new List<byte>();
       a.AddRange(client.socketBuffer.Take(receive));
        totmsglen2 = ((int.Parse(a.GetRange(0, 2)[0].ToString()) * 256) + int.Parse(a.GetRange(0, 2)[1].ToString()) + 2);
        if (a.Count != totmsglen2)
        {
          // this is not  valid messge discared it 
            a.RemoveRange(0,totmsglen2);
        }
        else
        {// valid message process it 
            client.outBuffer.AddRange(a.GetRange(0,totmsglen2));
            a.RemoveRange(0,totmsglen2);
        }
        do
        {
            client.EnvelopeRead();

            if (client.outBuffer.Count >= client.MessageLength)
            {
                var msg = client.outBuffer.GetRange(0, client.MessageLength).ToArray();
                client.outBuffer.RemoveRange(0, client.MessageLength);

                client.RaiseMessageReceived(msg, client.KindOfMessage);

                client.KindOfMessage = KindMessage.Unknown;
                client.MessageLength = client.outBuffer.Count >= Const.TotalSizeOfEnvelope ? 0 : int.MaxValue;
            }

        } while (client.outBuffer.Count >= client.MessageLength);
    }
}
```

The code works only for one message and not when continuous messages are received.

```
Cases:
0010aaaaaaaaa  valid  
0007asd        invalid  
0005iiiii      valid
```

Comment: Why are you locking on `client.outBuffer`? Is it exposed outside of the class? You really need a [mcve] for us.

Comment: it is a List of  Byte that is We make in client class.

Comment: when the message receive `client.socketBuffer`  then we extract in it add in to `Clint.outBuffer`  class.

Comment: when first message come it is exact length in `client.socketBuffer` when 2 times function call we have 2 message in `client.socketBuffer` how we get the message that comes second its length ??.

Answer (score 2):

> For example First four bit give me 45 and message length is 49 then this is true (45 body + first 4 bit length) else first four bit give 45 but message length 35 . drop this message.

The first 4 bytes **are** the "message length". There's no other way for a server to know when a message completes. So it's not *possible* to detect a mismatch.

> it also not secure for examples if they send the length 500 and message is 200 long then it fail, in this situation

Your protocol will just be waiting for the completion of that message. This is not a failure; it is by design. For example, if a client sends a length of 500 and a message that is 500, but if the packets got broken up, your sever could get a length of 500 with a message that is 200... and then seconds later get the other 300 of the message. That's the way TCP/IP works.

However:

> it also not secure

This is true. By following this simple approach, you allow two trivial denial-of-service attacks:

1. The client sends some huge message length, causing your server to allocate a huge buffer expecting some huge message.
2. The client only sends a partial message, causing your server to keep that buffer and socket allocated. A distributed attack can successfully consume a lot of your server resources.

To mitigate these attacks, you should do two things:

1. Have a reasonable maximum message size, and reject any client that tries to send a larger one.
2. Add an "idle timer" to each socket. Each time you receive data, reset the timer. When the timer goes off, kill the connection. Also, if the client is not sending *enough* data (i.e., the rate of data is too low for a period of time), then kill the connection.

Comment: Niece Solution it help me a lot and solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to make sure that the receiving logic only passes full messages back. Also you **cannot** assume that a full message (or even size info) is received always. So you would do something like:

Beginreceive(4 bytes length info) to start things off, then loop through EndReceive and new BeginReceives as long as the 4 bytes are not in.

Then BeginReceive(number of bytes expected) and again loop through EndReceive/BeginReceieve until you have all bytes in. That would be the moment to pass on the message to the decoding logic.

Comment: how we can check in message that is this is  4 byte are the length of the message. for example  first message is `000578945`   and second is `0010d788856566`  and when message receive in socket together is as `0005789450010d788856566` both message are in socket .

Comment: **check  this article**  [link](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html)

Comment: Maybe I don´t understand your question, but: I undestand that you are reading *all* the bytes that are available every time, I am suggesting (and the article you mentioned also) that you create one buffer of *4* bytes to read the length (and receive on that buffer), then create *another* buffer with length equals to the one received and read the message body. Only then pass on the message body.

Comment: This is true but it also not secure for examples if they send the length 500 and message is 200 long then it fail, in this situation .

Comment: If that possibility exists the you need to improve your protocol by adding a hash of the data, for example, or a checksum to validate the content of the messsage.